# Redirection 301 with htaccess

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect, http-status-code-301

I need to add this syntax below to many URL types :

&sort_order=price_low

Example 1 :

I need to redirect

example.com/cars-price/?make=toyota

to :

example.com/cars-price/?make=toyota&sort_order=price_low

it is applicable for many cars models, so i need to replace toyota by a dynamic variable

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Instead of editing the htaccess file yourself, you can use a plugin to do it for you. Check: https://wordpress.org/plugins/redirection/

This will add a 301 redirect.

Comment: Thanks, how to replace "toyota" on the Source URL and Target URL ? I tried ?make[^/]+ BUT it did not work